# Difference between create-react-app with backend node.js server and create-react-app without setting up node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, create-react-app

From udemy React courses i could see Brad Traversy using create-react-app with node.js backend server and Andrei Neagoie using only create-react-app without node.js server to develop a full stack product.

I am seriously confused with when to use what?

Can any one explain me between these two scenarios? Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly related to how you want to structure your code. You can either :-

1. Set up your front-end and back-end code together. So, in your script tags in package.json, you will have something like 'nodemon server.js && react start' (refer package.json for exact syntax) to start both front-end and server with 'npm start'
2. Setting up front-end and back-end separately.
   This is preferred for separation of concerns. In this case, you would start each separately.

Also, your front-end shouldn't be concerned about how your backend code has been written. It should only be dealing with backend using an API.
For ex: if in future, you wanted to change to Deno.js instead of node.js server, you would have make some modifications in package.json if you had front-end and back-end code written together in folder.

As far as deployment is concerned, in this case also, it will help if you kept the front-end and back-end code separately so you can deploy them separately.

Comment: Thanks lot. So actually create-react-app doesnt need a backend server setup by default. create-react-app itself acts as a backend. Right? This is just to confirm my understanding.

Comment: No! create-react-app only gives you front-end code. you might think that a server is running on your machine, but that server is only hosting your html,css,javascript. Andrei creates backend-code later on in the course using node.js and has a different repository for that

Answer (score 1):

React is used for frontend, while node.js is used for backend.

I think your confused because one is using react with node.js the other is using react alone.

Well React can be used for other backend other than node.js, like php for example.
This means you can create an app using react/php.

The reason Brad Traversy is using create-react-app with node.js because he wants to use node.js for his backend. 
While Andrei Neagoie is using create-react-app without node.js because he either:

1. Don't want to use any backend.
2. He will add backend later on.

Comment: This helps me to some extend. Thanks. But can you help me on this too? I developed Andrei course using only create-react-app without any backend server setup and published it to  heroku. How could this works without a backend server?

Comment: Here's a blog on heroku about that https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration hope it helps.